# how to rename a file like a weblink (http://...)

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line

I need to rename a file like a link, but if I try to rename it with `mv file.gif http://link/123/file.gif` it won't work.

I've tried to escape the Slash / with a Backslash \ , but with no success.

The Error that comes up tells me, that he didn't find the directory, because he sees the Slash as a layer of the directory tree.

Comment: `/` is one of only two characters that are not allowed in filenames, as it is the pathname delimiter character. The other one is the `nul` character since it is a string terminator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/` is the character that delimit components in a Unix file path. That character cannot occur in a directory entry's name. `http://link/123/file.gif` is the `file.gif` file inside a `123` directory itself inside the `link` directory itself inside the `http:` directory, itself in the current working directory.

To rename it to that file at that path, you'd need to create the directories first:

```
mkdir -p http:/link/123 &&
  mv file.gif http://link/123/file.gif
```

To rename the `file.gif` entry for that file in the current directory to that URL but with the `/`s replaced with `\`s, in Bourne/csh/rc-like shells:

```
mv file.gif 'http:\\link\123\file.gif'
```

In the `fish` shell, you'd still need to escape the `\` inside single-quotes:

```
mv file.gif 'http:\\\\link\\123\\file.gif'
```

Another option could be to use a character that looks like `/` (U+002F solidus) such as `⁄` (U+2044, the *fraction slash*):

```
mv file.gif 'http:⁄⁄link⁄123⁄file.gif'
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need a normal `/` and not a `\\` in the filename.

Comment: And creating the directory first unfortunately didn't help me either

Comment: You must create the whole hierarchy of directories, ie. first `http:` (with the colon at the end) in the same directory where `file.gif` is, then inside this directory `link`, then inside `link` directory `123`. Then return to the directory where `file.gif` is and type `mv file.gif http://link/123/file.gif`. It should work now.

Comment: @raj, that's what `mkdir -p` in my answer does.

Comment: I know :), but as @Scamus says it doesn't work for him, maybe he needs more detailed description.

Comment: I just tried this, but it's just moving the file to the last directory in the hierarchy, but the File has still the old name. And the option with the fraction slash won't work unfortunately, because the name should function like a link after it is transferred to the customer

Comment: @Scamus, yes, as I said that's what it does. A directory entry name cannot contain a `/` (cannot contain the 0x2F byte on ASCII-based systems). There is no way around that.

Comment: That's unfortunate. But thanks for the help :)